Mongoose One to Many populate with string _id
I have the PropertySchema which has multiple customers of type CustomerShema.
That's the PropertySchema
const propertySchema = new Schema({
  **_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }**,
  customers: [ {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer'
  }]
}, { collection: "Properties", timestamps: true });

const PropertySchema = mongoose.models.Property || mongoose.model("Property", propertySchema);
export default PropertySchema;

and this is the CustomerSchema:
const customerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    property: {
        type: **mongoose.Schema.Types.String**,
        ref: 'Property',
        required: true
    }
}, { collection: "Customers" });

When I do const customers = await CustomerSchema.find().populate("property"); it DOES NOT populate the property field.
Note that the _id of the PropertySchema is a String and not an ObjectId (I need it to be like so).
Does it could be this the problem? If so, how can I populate it?
On the other hand, const property = await PropertySchema.findById(params.property).populate("customers");, perfectly populates the customers field.
Thank you in advanced!
